# Unable to refresh lifetime statistics

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, reports

if I want to update the lifetime statistics it quickly returns 'Unable to refresh lifetime statistics.'

The only statistics I can refresh using the lifetime option are 
- coupons
- most viewed

[image: errors]

All the others return the above error, without even running for a very long time (within just a few seconds).

Refreshing daily statistics works.

How can I find the bug here?

edit: I'm running CE 1.8.1

I receive the following bugtrace:

```
    2014-03-14T14:40:08+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`usr_p194982_2`.`sales_order_aggregated_created`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SALES_ORDER_AGGREGATED_CREATED_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON D)' in /html/dev/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /html/dev/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /html/dev/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /html/dev/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /html/dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /html/dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#5 /html/dev/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#6 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Report/Order/Createdat.php(229): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sa...')
#7 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Report/Order/Createdat.php(55): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Order_Createdat->_aggregateByField('created_at', NULL, NULL)
#8 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Report/Order.php(55): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Order_Createdat->aggregate(NULL, NULL)
#9 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/StatisticsController.php(159): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Order->aggregate()
#10 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Report_StatisticsController->refreshLifetimeAction()
#11 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('refreshLifetime')
#12 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /html/dev/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /html/dev/index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`usr_p194982_2`.`sales_order_aggregated_created`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SALES_ORDER_AGGREGATED_CREATED_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON D)' in /html/dev/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /html/dev/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /html/dev/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /html/dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /html/dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#4 /html/dev/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#5 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Report/Order/Createdat.php(229): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sa...')
#6 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Report/Order/Createdat.php(55): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Order_Createdat->_aggregateByField('created_at', NULL, NULL)
#7 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Report/Order.php(55): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Order_Createdat->aggregate(NULL, NULL)
#8 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/StatisticsController.php(159): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Order->aggregate()
#9 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Report_StatisticsController->refreshLifetimeAction()
#10 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('refreshLifetime')
#11 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /html/dev/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /html/dev/index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

Comment: I've disabled all app/local and app/community modules to see if one of my installed modules could cause the issue, but it still has the same error.

Comment: Yes, I am running a multistore - 2 stores from the same core.

Comment: Have you recently deleted a store?

Comment: No, not as far as I am aware. The store was updated by my predecessor, who then left the project with me after the go live. It quickly became apparent that it wasn't by any means ready, so I had to fix issues asap and learning magento asap although actually coming from a few years of drupal development. The store goes back to 2009 and has orders from back then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error could be anything from syntax errors in an extension that overrides the default resource collection to a database error. Lifetime stats refresh is handled by a method implemented on each individual resource model - that method is called `aggregate` and it is wrapped in a try/catch block to prevent exceptions from being displayed to the user.

Line 159 (CE 1.8) of `Mage_Adminhtml_Report_StatisticsController` is the part of the `catch` that is key to figuring out the issue:

```
Mage::logException($e);
```

Which tells me that, if you have logging enabled, the file `var/log/exception.log` should contain a stack trace that tells you specifically what the error is.  To enable logging, navigate to System > Configuration > Developer and enable the logs.

In reality, the most likely scenario is that it is a db exception or a PHP out of memory error.

**Edit**

So, it seems as if you're getting a foreign key constraint error:

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_SALES_ORDER_AGGREGATED_CREATED_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`)
```

This can come up because the store it's trying to enter no longer exists. I would debug this by getting a list of current store ids:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(store_id) as stores from core_store;
```

And matching it up with a list of historical sales store ids:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT store_id) as stores from sales_flat_order;
```

If the store ids don't match, you're probably going to need to replace the old ids on the old orders. Either try to inventory and update the orders manually with the correct store id, or change it to `0` - the admin store.

**Other thoughts**

You may also want to try truncating the `sales_order_aggregated_created` table and re-running. Be extremely careful when truncating tables - always run (and test) a backup, do it when store is in maintenance mode, and test it on a staging/dev box prior.

Comment: Phil, thanks you very much for your comment! I did indeed get an bugtrace - added to my first post

Comment: I'm not seeing it @tecjam

Comment: Now hopefully ;)

Comment: See update for some pointers.

Comment: Thanks Phil, I am running in a dev environment. I'll check your thoughts and test it out over the weekend. Thanks again for your help =)

Comment: Just as an update: Stores from the core_store table: 0,1,2
Stores from the sales_flat_order table: 1,2,4

Store 4 does no longer exists. There is only one order on that store id, however, when trying to manually edit the order, or that customer id, Magento returns a 404 page not found error.

Comment: I tried to change the store_id value directly in the db. Now I can refresh the lifetime statistics for nearly every report type, apart from tax and orders.

Comment: Finally, I also searched for store_id in the sales_order_aggregated_created table and also set it to the id I previously set in the sales_flat_order. Now it all works! Thanks for your help. =)